# How to disable the red underline in the output PDF file?

Tags: pdf, underline

in the output PDF file there are some unwanted red/green unterlines:

[image]

And all over the contents:

[image]

I am using latex workshop 8.13.2 on Vscode and I can't find the relevant setting. How could I disable the annoying spell check?

(Ps. I don't want to turn off the spell check for the source code. The problem is in the generated PDF file.)

Thanks!

Comment: That's not spell check, those are hyperlinks made by hyperref.  Try `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` before `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have `pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}` somewhere in your document (or in a template file you are using), which makes underlined links, according to the `hyperref` manual:

> Links can be underlined instead of the default rectangle or options `colorlinks`, `frenchlinks`. This is done by option `pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}`.

Either replace that by `hidelinks`, or if you can't find it, add `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` in your preamble as @PhelypeOleinik said. Here's a sample code for you to play with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
% \hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}} % <-------- You have
\hypersetup{hidelinks} % <-------- You want
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Intro}\label{sec}
\cite{article-full}, see section~\ref{sec}.
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

The output, as promised, without underlining:

[image]

Comment: Amazing! I added "hidelinks" to \hypersetup{} and problem solved.